# How to dynamically render the user data in a component on button click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm new in React and got stuck on how can I achieve this.

After the user fills the field CEP from the first card and click on the button 'Gravar Dados', it shows a second card with all the information from the first card.

Template Picture:
[image: Template Picture]

New Result Picture:
[image: New Result Picture]

What I need is dynamically create another card, under the second card with new info from the first card.

This is what I've done so far.

I have this component `DadosPessoais.js` which is the second card in the Template Picture:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="card shadow mt-5" >
            <div className="card-header">
                <span>Dados Pessoais </span>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">

                <div className="row">

                    <div className="col-4">

                        <div>
                            <span>Cep: <strong>{this.props.cep}</strong></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>Bairro: <strong>{this.props.bairro}</strong></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="col-5">

                        <div>
                            <span>Rua: <strong>{this.props.rua}</strong></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>Cidade: <strong>{this.props.cidade}</strong></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="col-3">

                        <div>
                            <span>UF: <strong>{this.props.uf}</strong></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In my `Home.js` I have a form with `onSubmit` that calls `mostrarDadosPessoais` function:

Function:

```
      mostrarDadosPessoais(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      listaDados: this.state.listaDados.concat({
        cep: e.target.value,
        rua: e.target.value,
        bairro: e.target.value,
        cidade: e.target.value,
        uf: e.target.value,
      }),
    });
  }
```

And my input components `UserInput`, Should it be like this?:

```
            <div className="col-3">
              <UserInput name="Rua" Label="Rua" Id="Rua" value={this.state.rua} Disabled />
            </div>

            <div className="col-3">
              <UserInput name="Bairro" Label="Bairro" Id="Bairro" value={this.state.bairro} Disabled />
            </div>

            <div className="col-3">
              <UserInput name="Cidade" Label="Cidade" Id="Cidade" value={this.state.cidade} Disabled />
            </div>

            <div className="col-1">
              <UserInput name="UF" Label="UF" Id="UF" value={this.state.uf} Disabled />
            </div>
```

And to show the result card I've done this:

```
<div className="col-md-4">
        {this.state.listaDados.length === 0
          ? null
          : this.state.listaDados.map((lista) => (<DadosPessoais {...lista} />))}
      </div>
```

This is my `state`:

```
this.state = {

  listaCidade: [],

  listaDados: [],
}
```

Any ideas on how can I create another component and keep the values from the first one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you need a list of elements, displayed on the right, that will show user-entered data. You need the user to be able to enter many addresses through the form on the left, and you want each address to display on the right.

I would solve this with a component that contains state for all the elements you need to display in an array that you update on a form submit event, because that's an easy event to work with when you have forms with lots of fields. You can grab the values of the components through the event object e.

```
class StateContainer extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         addresses: [],
      }
   }

   mostrarDadosPessoais(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
         listaDados: this.state.listaDados.concat({ 
            cep: e.target.cep.value,
            rua: e.target.rua.value,
            // etc, etc
         }),
      })
   }
   render() {
      return (
      <div>
         <form handleSubmit={this.mostrarDadosPessoais}>
            {/* left-side form */}
            <input name="msg" />
            <button type="submit"></button>
         </form>
         <div>
            {/* right-side list of elements */}
            {this.state.addresses.length === 0 
               ? null 
               : this.state.addresses.map(
                  (address) => (<DadosPessoais {...address} />)
                 )
             }
         </div>
      </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but i've never used refs before, can you explain how to use in my case? I dont know how can i create a new component if the component was once created.

Comment: In your mockup, you have a box with inputs and a box to the right that displays those values. Have you successfully gotten the box on the right to show up?

If you have gotten the box on the right to show up, you can use the same technique to make the 'next card' show up - a 'show next' flag in the same element's state.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your requirements in my first response, I re-read your question and I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: i've tried your solution but still didnt achieve what i need, i guess i'm doing something wrong, how should i set the state? Now im getting an empty second card, i did this in the mostrarDadosPessoais method: this.setState({

      listaDados: [{
        cep: this.state.cep, rua: this.state.rua, bairro: this.state.bairro, cidade: this.state.cidade, uf: this.state.uf
      }, { msg: this.state.listaDados }]
    })

Comment: You can delete `{ msg: this.state.listaDados }`, then it might work. That was an example I used to avoid typing out all of this -- `{ cep: this.state.cep, rua: this.state.rua, bairro: this.state.bairro, cidade: this.state.cidade, uf: this.state.uf }`. Sorry for the misleading example!

Comment: Whoops, read and responded too fast again, didn't say the right thing. You can delete `{ msg: this.state.listaDados }`, and use `setState({ listaDados: this.state.listaDados.concat({ cep: e.target.cep.value, rua: e.target.rua.value, etc })`. I'll edit the answer to reflect this clarification. Don't forget to add a 'name' attribute to your inputs in the form! For example: `<input name="cep" />`

Comment: Right my friend, i have updated my question, but im feeling we are almost there!!! Now its duplicating the cards perfectly but the values are not being passed, do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: I got it !! the error was on this piece of code inside the setState in mostrarDadosPessoais function: cep: e.target.cep.value.... when i changed it to cep: this.state.cep and so on it worked!! Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge! i've learned a lot! would pay you a beer! Thanks friend.